# Eigenvector and orthogonal matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, orthogonal-matrices

If $D$ is a diagonal matrix and $P$ is an orthogonal matrix where $P^{-1} = P^T$.

If $y= PDP^T$ , why is $y^{100} = P D^{100} P^T$ and not $P^{100} D^{100} {(P^T)}^{100}$ ?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site, please consider learning mathjax / latex typesetting as it is used much on this site. I can help show you this first time how you can do it. You can hit "edit" button to see how the code is written, and there is also some tutorial here on the site you can probably find.

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) it is!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, let's take a look at $y^2 = PDP^T \cdot PDP^T$. The $P^T$ and $P$ in the middle cancel out because $P^T$ is the inverse of $P$. That means this can be simplified to $y^2 = PD^2P^T$. Do you see the pattern?